# Creating SQL "Loops"

Tags: sql, r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following tables stored on a server : `"my_table1", "my_table2", "my_table3", "my_table4", "my_table5"`

I am trying to write a LOOP that performs SQL statements on these tables. As an example:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

names = c("my_table1", "my_table2", "my_table3", "my_table4", "my_table5")
limits = abs(as.integer(rnorm(5,100,100)))

mycon = dbConnect(...)

results = list()

for (i in 1:length(names))

{

file_i = dbGetQuery(mycon, "select * from names[i] limit limits[i]")
results[[i]] = file_i

}

final_results <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
```

But I don't think the dbgetquery() statement is able to recognize the SQL in this format.

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out safe string interpolation: https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/sqlinterpolate or https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create the sql statement you have to use

```
paste("select * from ",names[i]," limit ",limits[i])
```

instead of

```
"select * from names[i] limit limits[i]"
```

Comment: @ celimi: thank you so much! Can you please show me how I would use this?

Comment: file_i = dbGetQuery(mycon, paste("select * from ",names[i]," limit ",limits[i]) )

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this should work.

Comment: Though this method is very prone to SQL injection problems and any names that may have characters that could interfere with the SQL syntax. It's much safer to use something like `sqlInterpolate` to correctly build SQL statements.

Comment: @MrFlick, `sqlInterpolate` cannot work with the table name, since it ensures it is a string literal and not a quoted identifier; c.f., `sqlInterpolate(con, "select 1 from ?a limit ?b", a="foo", b=2L)` returns `<SQL> select 1 from 'foo' limit 2`, where `'foo'` should ?ideally? be `"foo"` (the `2` works fine). Perhaps `DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier` on `names` (optionally inside the `paste`) would be acceptable.

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY yeah. I left the link on the original question which had examples doing exactly that. I guess I should have repeated it here as well.

Comment: @ MrFlick: thank you for your reply! Can you please explain what kinds of problems can occur? If you have time, could you please post an answer that uses "sqlInterpolate"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need for an explicit `for` loop, we can do it with

```r
results <-
  Map(function(nm, lim) dbGetQuery(mycon, paste("select * from", nm, "limit", lim)),
      dbQuoteIdentifier(mycon, names), limits)
```

Alternatively, generating the queries *up front* then `lapply`ing over them:

```r
queries <- paste("select * from", dbQuoteIdentifier(mycon, names), "limit", limits)
results <- lapply(queries, dbGetQuery, conn = mycon)
```